# macOS: SwiftUI have a Menu Item that changes WKWebView URL and main window title?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

EDIT: Decided to change the approach:

Hi, I've created a menu item on my macOS SwiftUI app for "www.google.com".

I've used AppDelegate.swift to add

```
    @IBAction func google(_ sender: Any) {
        WebBrowserView.load(url: URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!)
    }
```

( which provides me with the error

```
Instance member 'load' cannot be used on type 'WebBrowserView'; 
did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
```

)

The ContentView.swift says

```
struct BrowserView: View {

    private let browser = WebBrowserView()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            browser
                .onAppear() {
                    self.browser.load(url: URL(string: "http://duckduckgo.com")!)
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I've also mapped the google.com Menu entry to First Responder in Main.Storyboard, and mapped it to google -function

Yet when I click on the main menu item google.com - nothing specifically happens. What am I doing wrong here?

At first I tried to copy the whole struct BrowserView from ContentView to AppDelegate, and wrap it inside the @IBAction, but that did not seem to work either.

EDIT: To evade the error, I attempted this:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private let browser = WebBrowserView()

    @IBAction func google(_ sender: Any) {
        self.browser.load(url: URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!)
    }
```

but, while I now no longer have an error, clicking on the main menu item does nothing.

I then decided to try yet another trial, which is to put everything in the applicationDidFinishLaunching into AppDelegate `@IBAction`.

```
    @IBAction func duckduckgo(_ sender: Any) {
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        window.title = "XReach WebClient https://duckduckgo.com"

        self.browser.load(url: URL(string: "http://duckduckgo.com")!)
    }
```

Now, while this does successfully change the title to duckduckgo, the browser still loads a previous URL instead.

What's the cleanest way of doing this?